# Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views - FATAL EXCEPTION

Tags: java, android

I am trying to use `setContentView` method to bring on my views to the front but on doing this i am getting this error.

From searching here *Similar questions* I found this error usually results when trying to get/set a value of layout view object for e.g. without instantiating it but that's not the case here, i am not even able to set the view.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.ticker);
    Thread tmr = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException iEx) {
                iEx.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                User usrObj = new User();
                if (usrObj.authenticateUser()) {

                    Intent mainActivity = new Intent(
                            "android.intent.action.Homeview");
                    startActivity(mainActivity);
                } else {
                    setContentView(R.layout.login); // <- ERROR
                    activateLogin();
                }
            }
        }

    };
    tmr.start();

}
```

Comment: UI related operations can only be handled by the UI thread. You are setting a view in a new Thread.  Use Message Handlers from the Thread to pass the information to the UI thread or use an AsynTask!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call [runOnUiThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) to change your a layout from a thread.

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() { 
        User usrObj = new User();
        if (usrObj.authenticateUser()) {
            Intent mainActivity = new Intent("android.intent.action.Homeview");
            startActivity(mainActivity);
        } else {
            setContentView(R.layout.login); // <- ERROR
            activateLogin();
        }
    }
});
```

As a side note, make sure you don't hardcode strings, in order to avoid typo issues.-

```
Intent mainActivity = new Intent(YourActivity.this, android.intent.action.Homeview.class);
```

Comment: You're correct, however the point of using separate threads is to mitigate the strain (and bottlenecks) on the main thread. So the `runOnUiThread` block should only wrap the calls that must be executed on the main thread.

Comment: @NitroNbg you're right. Anyway, this scenario doesn't look like a performance issue, the thread is used just to delay the launch of the next activity (most probably this is the code of a splash screen).

Answer (score 1):

You're calling setContentView(...) from non-UI thread. Either move it to the main (UI) thread or wrap that single call in:

```
runOnUIThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        setContentView(R.layout.login);
    }
});
```